# Ignoring features in XGBoost by setting them as "missing"

Tags: xgboost, feature-engineering

I have some data `n x m` and I want to ignore certain features. One idea I had is to mark those features as "missing", since XGBoost can handle missing values by default, e.g. using `nan` when constructing the `DMatrix`:

```py
n, m = 100, 10

X = np.random.uniform(size=(n, m))
y = (np.sum(X, axis=1) >= 0.5 * m).astype(int)

# ignore certain features: mark them as missing
X[:, 2:7] = np.nan

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y, missing=np.nan)
model = xgb.train(params={'objective': 'binary:logistic'}, dtrain=dtrain)
```

My question is whether now all such missing features will be ignored during inference. Experimentally, I observed that if I feed the model a `dtrain` matrix copy, but such that the missing values are filled with random data, I get the same predictions as on  the original `dtrain`:

```py
X2 = X.copy()
X2[np.isnan(X2)] = np.random.uniform()

np.allclose(
    model.predict(dtrain), 
    model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X2, missing=np.nan)),
    rtol=0,
    atol=1e-12
) # True
```

Is it safe to say that, in general, any missing values during train, but **which may be present during inference** are ignored? Are there any caveats?

Comment: it is not clear what you wnat to achieve. Why not removing them both from training and testing data ? you have training data of different size ?

Comment: The training and test data are of the same size. Since the test data cannot be changed, I just want to ignore certain features during training, so they can also be ignored during testing / inference.

Comment: why not just removing them then ? using only X[Features] ?

Comment: I know this is possible, but I want to know specifically if masking a feature during training allows ignoring that feature during testing.

Comment: You can in the sense that the libariry allows you to but I would be concerned by the shift. As is, what you achieve really depends on your features. Is X2 an usefull feature that the model learned ? or is it unused by the model because it isn't statistically pertinent ? What  you want to do would require significant investigative work that depends on your dataset / the learning strat... we cannot answer those questions with the toy exemple you provided.

Comment: Assume that features indexed `2:7` are uninformative to the model, or worse, that they are wrongly computed. Assume further that they cannot be removed per se. Now, I want to train on a DMatrix with those features masked for all examples, so the model learns to completely ignore them. Finally, during test / inference, the feature vectors may contain those values (that I ignored during training). Here lies my question: Is there a guarantee that the model will continue to ignore them? I would assume so, because there would be no paths in the tree making use of those features.

Comment: You haven't clarified why you can't remove the features at all. But yeah you can imagine solutions. One would be to make the same correction on the testing data, another would be to add a columns with a binary flag 'possibly wrongly computed'. All of this is in the domain of possible but generally not a good idea. Regarding the behavior of the model there is no garantee, as it might learn stuff on the non-masked data. So your imputation might have some impact. Best way to go would be to mask on both training and testing and call that part of the data cleaning process if your boss ask.

Comment: Right, but generally, once the model is trained, if certain features do not become part of the decision process learned (e.g. they are non-informative), then it does not matter what values these features have on some test data, as they'll be completely ignored.